# React: Dynamically pass Img Src into Child Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a child component that should receive an `icon=..` property to dynamically load an image. The images work when statically specified as `img src={name}`, but not when dynamically passed through properties, even if I import them in both the Parent & Child.

```
import laptopHouse from './../images/icons/laptop-house.svg'

export default function Infographic(props) {
    return (


        <Col lg={4} className="home-tile" id="my-telework-tile">
            <img src={props.icon} className="home-tile-img" alt=""/>
            <div className="home-tile-content">
                <h2>{props.title}</h2>
                <p>{props.text}</p>
            </div>
        </Col>

    );
}
```

Usage

```
import laptopHouse from './../images/icons/laptop-house.svg'

export default function Home(props) {
    return (
         <Infographic icon="laptopHouse" title="Welcome" text="This is an infographic" />
    );
}
```

Comment: can you make a list of icon props?

Comment: Yes, they can be hard-coded. How would I do that?

Comment: Oh, I see, you've a typo in your usage, `icon="laptopHouse"` should be `icon={laptopHouse}`. Voting to close as "Unreproducible, caused by typo." The component code is fine, see this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dynamically-pass-img-src-into-child-component-c5j5p).

Comment: You mistakenly passed `laptopHouse' as string and not value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud pass "**laptopHouse**" in {curly braces}

Answer (score 1):

I have a few solutions.

1. pass the resource with `curly braces`

```
import laptopHouse from './../images/icons/laptop-house.svg'

export default function Home(props) {
    return (
         <Infographic icon={laptopHouse} title="Welcome" text="This is an infographic" />
    );
}
```

2. pass the img itself

```
export default function Infographic(props) {
    return (
        <Col lg={4} className="home-tile" id="my-telework-tile">
            {props.children}
            <div className="home-tile-content">
                <h2>{props.title}</h2>
                <p>{props.text}</p>
            </div>
        </Col>

    );
}


import laptopHouse from './../images/icons/laptop-house.svg'

export default function Home(props) {
    return (
         <Infographic title="Welcome" text="This is an infographic">
           <img src={laptopHose} className="home-tile-img" alt=""/>
         </Infographic>
    );
}
```